# Java: Trouble with importing CSV values into a SQL Server DECIMAL field

Tags: java, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using SQLServerBulkCopy to import CSV files into a database.  The code is:

```
    private void bulkCopy(String tableName, String csvFileName) throws Exception {
    Integer rowCount = 0;        
    Instant copyStart = Instant.now();

    try {
        Integer column = 0;
        SQLServerBulkCopy copier = new SQLServerBulkCopy(dbConnection);
        SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord fileRecord = new SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord(csvFileName, true);
        Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();

        // Set the metadata for the column to be copied, as well as mapping the columns.
        for (String thisColumn : commonColumns) {
            column += 1;
            Integer index = tableData.columns.indexOf(thisColumn);
            Integer size = tableData.sizes.get(index);
            Integer type = getType(tableData.types.get(index));
            
            fileRecord.addColumnMetadata(index + 1, thisColumn, type, size, 0);
            copier.addColumnMapping(thisColumn, thisColumn);
        }
        // System.exit(0);

        copier.setDestinationTableName(tableName);
        copier.writeToServer(fileRecord);
        rowCount = getRowCount(statement, tableName);
        copier.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        throw e;
    }
    Instant copyEnd = Instant.now();
    Duration elapsed = Duration.between(copyStart, copyEnd);
    logger.info("DEBUG: file is " + csvFileName);

    logger.info("It took " + utils.formatDuration(elapsed) + " to write " + rowCount + " rows to the " + tableName + " table.");
}
```

The problem is a `DECIMAL(16,2)` field with a 100 in the CSV file.  When I try to run my code, I get this error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An error occurred while converting the '"100"' value to JDBC data type DECIMAL.

I have no idea how to keep this error from happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your number is not a number in your file. It is a String with the value 100.

Can you change the CSV File to have 100 instead of "100" or better can you activate the escaping of  field delimters in this SQLServerBulkCopy Object?
Is it this? https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/17569c6aa1347d1c691581055c4f7a98fc0ab813/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord.java#L555

Comment: Thanks for spotting that.  I have been looking at these through Excel, which strips out the quotes.  We get these files from a vendor, so I'll have to look into trying to escape the quotes.  I haven't done this in Java before, so am not as up to speed on this as I'd like.

Comment: I set the escaping of field delimiters to true and got:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to parse the CSV file, verify that the fields are correctly enclosed in double quotes.